# How to create custom filter in vuejs webpack loader template?

Tags: webpack, loader, vue.js

I  have seen in the documentation. It tell to create filter like

```
Vue.filter('reverse', function (value) {
  return value.split('').reverse().join('')
})
```

I tried to create filter in vuejs webpack loader as

```
export default {
  filter: {
    reverse: function(value) {
      return value.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
}
```

But its not working. COuld anyone suggest that how it should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `filters` in stead of `filter`:

```
export default {
  filters: {
    reverse: function(value) {
      return value.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the function checkFilters in the complied file vue.common.js

```
 /**
 * Check read/write filter stats.
 */

checkFilters: function checkFilters() {
  var filters = this.filters;
  if (!filters) return;
  var i = filters.length;
  while (i--) {
    var filter = resolveAsset(this.vm.$options, 'filters', filters[i].name);
    if (typeof filter === 'function' || filter.read) {
      this.hasRead = true;
    }
    if (filter.write) {
      this.hasWrite = true;
    }
  }
},
```

So if it is a one-way filter, it must be a function. If it is a two-way filter, it is an object with read property which is a function at least in it.

So, in a vue file, if you want to self-define a filter, you should write like this:

```
export default {
  filters: {
    "reverse": function(value) {
      return value.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
}
```

If it is a two-way filters, you should write like this:

```
export default {
  filters: {
    "reverse": { 
      read: function(value) {
        return value.split('').reverse().join('')
      },
      write: function(val, oldVal) { //this is not neccessary
       //something you want to return
      }
    }
  }
}
```